# Chromium snap can't access /home/user/repos/myrepo files, and I intended to use the dev console, and I find no way around it

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, snap, chromium

So I've got Xubuntu. I typically use Firefox, but I'm learning front-end with JS.

I can use the dev tools of FF, but I wanted to try the tools on Chrome/ium too. There's not deb available so I installed through snap.

Reading the docs I've seen that there's a --classic mode that would allow the app to access local files, but apparently this is only possible if the app was intended for so, which isn't the case for chromium. IIRC I can't force this mode on chromium.

Searching around I see no way to circunvent this, nor in the documentation. I'm I reading wrong or I just can't develop with Chrome in Ubuntu?

Comment: Chrome & Chromium are different programs; chrome is available as a *deb* package; where the default `chromium` is available as a *snap* for recent releases. Snap packages have higher levels of security; and don't see the / file-system, only $HOME or certain other directories if `snap connect` option removable-media is enabled.  You're wanting a lower level of security than *snap* packages allow (*classic confinement* is more limited than you indicate too!)

Comment: So that means if I manage to activate that option you mention, chromium should be able to acess $home sub dirs, or just first level files under $home?

Comment: It can access your $HOME (ie. your `/home/$USER`) and specified removable media directories (ie. `/mnt` & `/media`); it will **not** allow you to read other users directories - that goes against security rules.  But this rule applies to `chromium` as snap; and not google-chrome (chrome is a different application to chromium)

Comment: I see, thank you. So I guess I'm forced to install chrome then.